# How do I use the Malayalam language in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I have installed Malayalam fonts from Software Center on my Ubuntu 13.04 installation. In LibreOffice Writer I can see the installed Malayalam fonts like Meera, Rachana.

I would like to create a document in Malayalam fonts. I activated it in fonts selecting to **Meera** and **Rachana**, but when I type in document it's still English.

I hope I haven't enabled some options I shouldn't have. Please guide me the right way to attain my requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! "But when I type in document its still English." Do you mean English/Latin characters or the language selection for spelling check?

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I can type malayalam with IBUS. But cannot get the "ttf" styles. copying ml-karthika to .fonts makes no difference.
Is there any thing that I have to do after

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the Malayalam keyboard layout.  To do that just follow the images below.

Click on Keyboard Layout

[image]

Click the + sign to add a layout

[image]

Choose that correct layout that you want, and then click add

[image]

To switch languages, you can either use that key combination shown in the image below

[image]

Or

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Libre office Writer go to Tools -> Options -> Fonts -> Basic fonts(CTL), set desired malayalam font and font size. It automatically choose font you likes when switch to malayalam key board layout. Use **[unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)** fonts to view or type Malayalam language in Ubuntu. You can download latest version of Malayalam Unicode fonts provided by **Swathanthra Malayalam Computing** from [**here**](http://wiki.smc.org.in/Fonts). Kaumudi Malayalam Unicode font provided by **Kerala Kaumudi** is available **[here](http://news.keralakaumudi.com/info/Kaumudi.ttf)**

Answer (score 1):

You may want to follow the instructions from both the other current answers - as this "answer" doesn't address the fonts directly.

Once you have the fonts, you may still have to "tell" LibreOffice about them under Tools->Options->Language Settings->Languages and ...->Writing Aids. If it doesn't see them, then some additional steps may be necessary (probably easy, but I don't know what they would be.)

Long ago and far away, there used to be a font importer for OpenOffice, but that may be a thing of the past.

In addition, you may want to go into your package manager and install libreoffice-l10n-ml. This will translate Libreoffice itself into Malayam.

I did not see them in my package manager, but you would probably want the Malayam packages for the thesaurus, spell checker, and hyphenation as well.

If you don't get everything set with help here, try posting on the OpenOffice/LibreOffice forums. For this question, I would start here: http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewforum.php?f=101  . (The buzzwords to use (in addition to fonts) would be Malayam localization. That forum is in English, but you may also be able to find support in other languages.)

Answer (score 0):

You can download Karthika Fonts [here](http://www.fonts2u.com/ml-ttkarthika-normal.font)
Extract the file and copy paste into your home/.fonts directory. restart system. you will be able to type in malayalam, and even view/edit malayalam documents created in MSword.
please do post your feedback.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use Varamozhi and copy paste the text into Libre Office. Another option is to use the Google Transliteration IME offline installer with WINE. Later option is not tried by me.